# unity the name ' unzip ' does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Help me about this error please I searches a lot but found nothing.

```
/*====== Copyright (c) 2013-2014 Qualcomm Connected Experiences, Inc. All Rights Reserved. Qualcomm Confidential and Proprietary =========*/

using System.IO; 
using UnityEditor;

namespace Vuforia.EditorClasses  { 

    /// <summary> 
    /// class wrapping a JS functionality to unzip a file, registers itself at the Unzipper Singleton to provide the functionality. 
    /// </summary>
    [InitializeOnLoad] 
    public class SharpZipLibUnzipper : IUnzipper { 
        /// <summary> 
        /// register an instance of this class at the singleton immediately 
        /// </summary> 
        static SharpZipLibUnzipper() {
            Unzipper.Instance = new SharpZipLibUnzipper(); 
        } 

        public Stream UnzipFile(string path, string fileNameinZip) {
            #if !EXCLUDE_JAVASCRIPT 
            return Unzip.Unzip(path, fileNameinZip); 
            #else return null; 
            #endif 
        } 
    } 
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You realize you are violating the copyright of Qualcomm Connected Experiences?

Comment: Often I get this error when saving a script while running Vuforia. Closing and restarting removes the error for me. @rene Why is he violating? The SharpZipLibUnzipper class is part of the Vuforia package.

Comment: @Everts there is a copyright notice in the code snippet and by posting here the content is re-licensed as cc-by-sa but the copyright on the original code prohibits that. I have already checked that it is not something that will be enforced by SE or the mod team but the original copyright holder has the legal right to prosecute and/or file a [DMCA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291995/do-stack-exchange-sites-allow-to-include-copyright-license-in-code-snippets/291998#291998) request. So it is more a warning then anything else.

Comment: Ooooh ok I see.

Comment: But this is a open source code check from github.com

Comment: @Newbie no it is not open source, as the code is apparently not licensed under an open source license. the code is merely available. cryengine is a good exampe of this: the whole code is on GitHub https://github.com/CRYTEK/CRYENGINE, but it has its own very limiting license, and only allows to publish software that builds on it as object code, not source code.

Comment: I am getting exactly the same error. Is anyone found the fix for this error?

Answer (score 8):

Change line to reference newer version of Vuforia. THEY SHOULD HAVE CLEANED THIS UP THEMSELVES

---

```
#if !EXCLUDE_JAVASCRIPT
    return Unzipper.Instance.UnzipFile(path, fileNameinZip);
#else
    return null;
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you build but get an error during the build. Vuforia tries to reimport the elements but do not find it. You can either correct the error and switch platform, and get back to the one you are building on, or relaunch the editor.

Comment: I updated, closed, relaunched many times. Still, I have the same error. Is someone know the fix for this bug?